# Find all irreducible characters of $C_2\times C_3$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory, cyclic-groups, characters

Find all the irreducible characters of $C_2\times C_3$. Note here that $C_n$ is a cyclic group of order n.

I have calculated the character tables for $C_2$ and $C_3$ and this is what I got:

$C_2$:
$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|} 
 & \text{E} & \text{$C_2$} & \text{Rotations} & \text{Quadratic}\\ \hline
\text{A} & 1 & 1 & z, R_z & x^2, y^2, z^2, xy \\ \hline
\text{B} & 1 & -1 & x, y, R_x, R_y & yz, xz\\ \hline
\end{array}$$

$C_3$:$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|} 
 & \text{E} & \text{$C_3$} & \text{($C_3$)$^2$} & \text{Rotations} & \text{Quadratic} & \text{Cubic functions}\\ \hline
\text{A} & 1 & 1 & 1 & z, R_z & x^2 + y^2, z^2 & z^3, y(3x^2-y^2), x(x^2-3y^2), z(x^2+y^2)  \\ \hline
\text{E} & 1, 1 & \epsilon, \epsilon^* & \epsilon, \epsilon^* & x+iy; R_x + R_y, x-iy;R_x-iR_y& (x^2-y^2, xy), (yz, xz) & (xz^2, yz^2), [xyz, z(x^2-y^2)], [x(x^2+y^2), y(x^2+y^2)]\\ \hline
\end{array}$$

I know that any representation of an abelian group has dimension $1$. $C_2 \times C_3$ will be abelian. Where would I go from here? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Why not instead use the fact that $g^6=1$ for all $g\in G:= C_2\times C_3\cong C_6$?  You then get immediately that every irreducible representation $\rho:G\to \text{GL}_1(\mathbb{C})\cong\mathbb{C}^\times$ sends $\gamma\mapsto z$ where $z^6=1$, where $\gamma$ is a fixed generator of $G$.

Comment: In general, the characters of a direct product are given by characters of the form $\chi(x,y) = \chi_1(x)\chi_2(y)$ for characters $\chi_1$ and $\chi_2$ of the factors.